# Chaining remote SQL Server Agent Jobs with success/failure feedback

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent, jobs

I have 2 `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4)` instances, residing on different servers.

`ServerA` has a linked server, pointing to `ServerB\InstanceB`.
Both instances have a job, and `JobA` triggers the remote execution of `JobB`.
So the execution of the jobs is chained.

Schematic of setup

- `ServerA\InstanceA`

  - Server Objects

    - Linked Servers

      - `LinkedServerToB` (target: `ServerB\InstanceB`)
  - SQL Server Agent

    - Jobs

      - `JobA`

        - Step1 = Execute some local code
        - Step2 = `EXEC [LinkedServerToB].[msdb].[dbo].sp_start_job @job_name="JobB"`
- `ServerB\InstanceB`

  - SQL Server Agent

    - Jobs

      - `JobB`

This all works fine.
Except for when `JobB` fails.
When that happens, `JobA`.`Step2` doesn't know about that.
All `JobA`.`Step2` did was *trigger* the remote execution of `JobB`, and then it's done.
So `JobA` in its entirety runs successfully, despite the failure of `JobB`.

Although I understand why it's behaving that way, its not the outcome I was looking for.
Instead, I'd like the parent job (`JobA`) to fail when a child job (`JobB`) fails.

How can I get `JobA` to fail when `JobB` fails?
Maybe some sort of success/failure feedback between them, but I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: Does JobB need to be a SQL Agent job? Could you instead implement the work done by it as a stored procedure, or series of stored procedures? That should enable synchronous calls and handling of returned errors.

Comment: @PhilipKelley `JobB` doesn't need to be a SQL Agent job. It acutally just calls a bunch of stored procedures on the remote machine. So you mean I should call those remote procedures within `JobA`?

Comment: That is definitely an option. It should permit better control, since execution should be synchronous (i.e. you don't "launch a job and done", as you pointed out). Note that I use "should" a lot--when it comes to Linked Servers, things can get very complex very quickly.

Comment: Are there other options that don't get very complex very quickly?

Comment: Possibly not. I found Linked Servers ugly to configure and hard to support. Another option is to have something outside the databases manage your multi-database task list (I've used Windows Scheduler in the past--ugly, but functional)... but then you have to write it, configure it with appropriate access, and everything else. Which turns into a big pile of "it depends on what you're actually trying to do", to determine how best to tackle it. It could be your current plan is a "best fit".

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a loop which polls serverB and checks whether the job has finished and what the outcome was. On each iteration of the loop make the job sleep using waitfor delay '00:02:00' (a 2 minute delay).

To check if the status on a job see the link below

https://sqljunkieshare.com/2014/11/21/get-sql-agent-job-status/